# Getting array value count and assigning ranking

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this below:

**Array**

```
Array
(
    [Team 1] => Array
        (
            [wins] => 60
        )

    [Team 2] => Array
        (
            [wins] => 12
        )

    [Team 3] => Array
        (
            [wins] => 79
        )

    [Team 4] => Array
        (
            [wins] => 36
        )

    [Team 5] => Array
        (
            [wins] => 29
        )

)
```

Then I have spans displaying the results like this using php `foreach`

**HTML**

```
<span><?php echo ['Team 1']['wins'] ?></span>
<span><?php echo ['Team 2']['wins'] ?></span>
<span><?php echo ['Team 3']['wins'] ?></span>
<span><?php echo ['Team 4']['wins'] ?></span>
<span><?php echo ['Team 5']['wins'] ?></span>
```

I would like the display some text next to each team, giving them a ranking, 1-5, based off their "wins" value. I would like the output to look like this. Is there a way to calculate the "wins" and give a ranking of 1 through 5 by using the wins value ?

**Expected Result**

```
<span><?php echo "#2" ['Team 1']['wins'] ?></span>
<span><?php echo "#5" ['Team 2']['wins'] ?></span>
<span><?php echo "#1" ['Team 3']['wins'] ?></span>
<span><?php echo "#3" ['Team 4']['wins'] ?></span>
<span><?php echo "#4" ['Team 5']['wins'] ?></span>
```

Comment: so you want someone to code for you, right ?

Comment: this is called **sort**ing. http://php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php

Comment: Might get an easier to use array `array_combine(array_keys($array), array_column($array, 'wins'));`

Comment: @stoggafu  check again, i have edited my answer, and sorry for the late answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with [`array multi_sort`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

**Array**

```
<?php 
$inventory = 
Array
(
    'Team 1'=> Array
        (
            'wins' => 60
        ),

    'Team 2' => Array
        (
            'wins' => 12
        ),

    'Team 3' => Array
        (
            'wins' => 79
        ),

    'Team 4' => Array
        (
            'wins' => 36
        ),

    'Team 5' => Array
        (
            'wins' => 29
        ),

);
?>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
$inventory2 = $inventory;
$kol = array();
$a = 1;

array_multisort($inventory, SORT_DESC);
foreach ($inventory as $key=>$value)
{
    $kol[$key] = $value;
    $kol[$key]['rank'] = $a++;
}

$ar = array_merge($inventory2,$kol);

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php foreach ($ar as $key => $value) { ?>
<span><?php echo $key ?></span><br> WINS : <?php echo $value['wins'] ?></span>
</br>Rank : <?php echo $value['rank'] ?></span>
</br></br>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this code, it should be sorting from the biggest to the smallest.

Comment: Thank you, this does well for the sorting part, however what I was trying to do was have a number in front of each one that showed a rank based on the highest to lowest amount of "wins". So Team 1 output should be #1, Team 2 output should be #5...etc

Comment: @stoggafu are we have to re arrange the position in html too ?

Comment: @stoggafu oh so you mean, the position of the team are the same like : `team 1`,`team 2`,`team 3`,`team 4`. But the position of `wins` for each eam is not sorted ?

Comment: I would like to add an additional field into each team that gives them a ranking of 1-5, based on the value of the wins field. So Team 1 would have 'rank' => 2 added in etc

Comment: Is this possible?

Comment: Does my answer help you? @stoggafu

Comment: Glad to help you :'